# Can plural form be the agent of Gerund?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, gerunds

Three men are on a deserted island when they find a lamp with a genie in it. After rubbing the lamp, the genie emerges and says, “I will give each of you one wish.” The first man says, “I wish I were home” and vanishes immediately. The second man says, “I wish I were home” and also disappears. The third man says, “I miss my friends, I wish they were here.” When hearing this joke, we activate our knowledge **about genies granting** three wishes.

Here, how come 'genies' is used instead of **genie's or genies'**.

Comment: "Genies" is not a genitive (possessive) noun here but a plural plain case noun functioning as the subject.

Comment: @BillJ is right. You do not need an apostrophe in any place. If you did put an apostrophe, due to the way the sentence would be formed, you would be talking about the genies’ granting abilities themselves.